# Opencv.js to detect rectangular shape from image and cut it

Tags: javascript, opencv

*i cant see output and also no error .... i try to detect rectangle shape from image and cut it and save it with opencv.js*

```
  onFilePicked() {
        let imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSrc');
        const files = event.target.files;
        imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
        var app = this
        imgElement.onload = function () {
            let mat = cv.imread(imgElement)
            let dst = new cv.Mat();

            cv.cvtColor(mat, mat, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
            // gray = cv.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
            cv.Canny(mat, dst, 30, 200, 3, false);

            let contours = new cv.MatVector();
            let hierarchy = new cv.Mat();

            var transformed = null

            cv.findContours(dst, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            var sortableContours = []
            for (let i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
                let cnt = contours.get(i);
                let area = cv.contourArea(cnt, false);
                let perim = cv.arcLength(cnt, false);

                sortableContours.push({
                    areaSize: area,
                    perimiterSize: perim,
                    contour: cnt
                });
                let color = new cv.Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
                let hierarchy2 = new cv.Mat();
                cv.drawContours(mat, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3);
            }
            cv.imshow('canvasOutput', mat);

            let foundContour = null;
            for (let sortableContour of sortableContours) {
                let peri = cv.arcLength(sortableContour.contour, true);
                let approx = new cv.Mat();

                cv.approxPolyDP(sortableContour.contour, approx, 0.1 * peri, true);

                if (approx.rows == 4) {

                    foundContour = approx
                    transformed = app.perspective_transform(mat, foundContour)

                    break;
                } else {
                    approx.delete();
                }

            }

            let rotate = app.rotate_image(transformed, 90)

            cv.imshow('canvasOutput', rotate)


        };

    },
```

> transform

```
  perspective_transform(image, foundContour) {

        let corner1 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[0], foundContour.data32S[1]);
        let corner2 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[2], foundContour.data32S[3]);
        let corner3 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[4], foundContour.data32S[5]);
        let corner4 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[6], foundContour.data32S[7]);

        //Order the corners
        let cornerArray = [{
            corner: corner1
        }, {
            corner: corner2
        }, {
            corner: corner3
        }, {
            corner: corner4
        }];
        //Sort by Y position (to get top-down)
        cornerArray.sort((item1, item2) => {
            return (item1.corner.y < item2.corner.y) ? -1 : (item1.corner.y > item2.corner.y) ? 1 : 0;
        }).slice(0, 5);

        //Determine left/right based on x position of top and bottom 2
        let tl = cornerArray[0].corner.x < cornerArray[1].corner.x ? cornerArray[0] : cornerArray[1];
        let tr = cornerArray[0].corner.x > cornerArray[1].corner.x ? cornerArray[0] : cornerArray[1];
        let bl = cornerArray[2].corner.x < cornerArray[3].corner.x ? cornerArray[2] : cornerArray[3];
        let br = cornerArray[2].corner.x > cornerArray[3].corner.x ? cornerArray[2] : cornerArray[3];

        //Calculate the max width/height
        let widthBottom = Math.hypot(br.corner.x - bl.corner.x, br.corner.y - bl.corner.y);
        let widthTop = Math.hypot(tr.corner.x - tl.corner.x, tr.corner.y - tl.corner.y);
        let theWidth = (widthBottom > widthTop) ? widthBottom : widthTop;
        let heightRight = Math.hypot(tr.corner.x - br.corner.x, tr.corner.y - br.corner.y);
        let heightLeft = Math.hypot(tl.corner.x - bl.corner.x, tr.corner.y - bl.corner.y);
        let theHeight = (heightRight > heightLeft) ? heightRight : heightLeft;

        //Transform!
        let finalDestCoords = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, [0, 0, theWidth - 1, 0, theWidth - 1, theHeight - 1, 0, theHeight - 1]); 
       // corners
        let srcCoords = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, [tl.corner.x, tl.corner.y, tr.corner.x, tr.corner.y, br.corner.x, br.corner.y, bl.corner.x, bl.corner.y]);
        let dsize = new cv.Size(theWidth, theHeight);
        let M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(srcCoords, finalDestCoords)
        let dst = new cv.Mat();

        cv.warpPerspective(image, dst, M, dsize);

        return dst

    },
```

> rotate image

```js
rotate_image(image, angle) {

            let dst = new cv.Mat();
            let dsize = new cv.Size(image.rows, image.cols);
            let center = new cv.Point(image.cols / 2, image.rows / 2);
            // You can try more different parameters
            let M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1);
            cv.warpAffine(image, dst, M, dsize, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, new cv.Scalar());

            return dst
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just grabbing the first contour in the entire array of sortableContours that has 4 points, and running the transform on that one. You need to sort them to those with the largest area first.

```
//sorts the contours by largest area first
let slicer = Math.min(sortableContours.length, 4);
let sortedContours = sortableContours.sort((a,b) => (a.areaSize < b.areaSize) ? 1 : -1).slice(0, slicer);
```

Also, I would recommend removing this line of code from within the for loop as it can be performed once outside the loop and slows the process down quite a bit (runs a few thousand times)

```
cv.drawContours(mat, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3);
```

My final note would be that the following line might need to be tweaked from .1 to a smaller number like .02 if you are getting poor results. .1 is more forgiving but .02 is more precise. Alternatively, you can do both, keep all the results in an array, and pick the one with the largest area when you are done for the best of both worlds.

```
cv.approxPolyDP(sortableContour.contour, approx, 0.1 * peri, true);
```

Best of both worlds:

```
//iterates through the largest contours and creates transformed images if the contour's shape is a rectangle
let transformedOptions = [];
for (let sortedContour of sortedContours) {
    let perimeter = cv.arcLength(sortedContour.contour, true);
    let precisePoly = new cv.Mat();
    let approxPoly = new cv.Mat();

    cv.approxPolyDP(sortedContour.contour, precisePoly, 0.02 * perimeter, true); //the smaller number (0.02) is more precise
    cv.approxPolyDP(sortedContour.contour, approxPoly, 0.1 * perimeter, true); //the larger number (0.1) is more forgiving

    //if the polygon has 4 points (rectangle-ish)
    if (precisePoly.rows == 4) {
        transformedOptions.push(this.perspectiveTransform(originalImage, precisePoly, imageHeight, imageWidth))
    }
    if(approxPoly.rows == 4) {
      transformedOptions.push(this.perspectiveTransform(originalImage, approxPoly, imageHeight, imageWidth))
    }

    precisePoly.delete();
    approxPoly.delete();
}

let transformed = this.getLargestTransformation(transformedOptions);

//this could be optimized a bit
private getLargestTransformation(options) {
var transformed = null;
for(let option of options) {
  if(option == null) continue;

  var largestArea = 0;
  var area = option.rows * option.cols;
  if(transformed == null || area > largestArea) {
    transformed = option;
    largestArea = area;
  }
}

return transformed;
```

}